# Buffering issue on Open pipe, write to file

Tags: perl

I've got a script that opens a process which kicks off an external program.  The external program writes to stdout and in the parent program I'm writing both to stdout and to file.  The print to stdout is immediate but the print to file is buffering. It must be waiting on some kind of Xk number before dumping it to file.  I've tried autoflush on the output file, the pipe, stdout, and also use stdbuf.  But nothing works as it only writes to the file in chunk messages.  Am I missing something?

```
      my $output = "/home/output.log";
      open(OL,">$output");
      OL->autoflush(1);
      open(P,'-|',"stdbuf -o0 -e0 external_program.py 2>&1");
      $| = 1;
      P->autoflush(1);
      STDOUT->autoflush(1);
      while(<P>) {
        chomp;
        print OL "$_\n";
        print "$_\n";
      }
      close(OL);
      close(P);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `stdbuf` does not work, but you can use the
[`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) command instead. Here is a simple example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
my $output = "output.log";
open(my $OL,">", $output) or die "Could not open file '$output': $!";
my $pid = open (my $P, '-|', "unbuffer test.pl 2>&1");
while(<$P>) {
    chomp;
    print $OL "$_\n";
    print "$_\n";
}
close $OL;
close $P;
```

where `test.pl` is given as:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
for (1..5) {
    print "Hello\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

You can install the `unbuffer` command on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install expect`

Without `unbuffer` command in the above script, all the five line with `Hello` prints at once after 5 seconds in the terminal window. When the `unbuffer` command is used, a new line with `Hello` appears every second.

**Update**:

Since your script is named `external_program.py` I assume it is a python program? Then there is a `-u` command line option to `python` that turns off buffering and you can use this option instead of running `unbuffer`.

Comment: Yes it is a python script and I already have the -u option running.

Comment: Did you remove the `stdbuf` command? Try `open(P,'-|',"python -u external_program.py 2>&1");` And still `output.log` is not updating?

Answer (score 0):

Hakon, I did already have the 'python3.6 -u external_program.py' running.  I finally found something that works.  If I change the print to file to flush every time it writes a line then it works

so I replace the following:

```
    OL "$_\n";<br>
    with
    OL->printflush("$_\n");
```

Comment: That's doesn't do anything that `OL->autoflush(1);` doesn't already do. `OL->printflush("$_\n");` prints, sets autoflush on, then restores the previous autoflush setting.

Comment: I want to be clear that I replaced the print inside the while loop with OL->printflush.  If there is no difference with OL->autoflush does that mean I should have put that inside the while loop as well?